# Configuring Sublime Text 3 for Ruby on Rails development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sublimetext3, sublimetext, development-environment

I am a beginner in this whole thing. I have previously used Sublime for HTML and CSS practice. Now I want to work on a website using Ruby, but do not know how to set up Sublime for rails, since every tutorial for Ruby has those files in the left side of the Sublime window, like App directory and similar generated somehow. I would not like to work blindfolded. I have tried to find a way to generate those directories, but did not find any step by step instructions. Which are welcomed in this case. I would appreciate those, or if there is a link to some detailed tutorial on how to do that. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directories you're talking about (`app`, `config`, etc.) aren't generated by SublimeText; they're generated by Rails when you create a new application with `rails new` at the command line.

Once you've created the application, you can open the top-level directory in SublimeText, and you'll see all the directories in your sidebar. For example, if you keep your apps in a directory called `my_app`, and you want to create a Rails app called `new_app`, you can do this from your terminal:

```
cd my_apps
rails new new_app
subl new_app
```

And you should see something like this:

[image: SublimeText screenshot]

For more on how to get started with Rails, I'd recommend Michael Hartl's [Ruby on Rails](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/) tutorial.

Comment: this one is helpful also, I do understand that they are created by rails, but did not know i need to create it through console, even though i do have start a console with ruby on this windows pc. Still not a huge fan of Linux. I have tried to use clud9, but they do not allow to register without credit card, so that is a no for me. I will try out those tutorials, Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

There is a blog that I hope it would help you in your case.

Here it is: [Setting up Sublime Text 3 for Rails Development](https://mattbrictson.com/sublime-text-3-recommendations)

Comment: Already checked this, but perhaps I was not paying enough attention, will try all the steps, hope it helps. Thank You!